# PhpStorm doesn't type hint magic constants

Tags: phpstorm

I just installed PhpStorm 2020.2.1 and while type hinting works for classes imported via "use", many built-in PHP classes and constants, such as `__NAMESPACE__`, `__DIR__` and the PDO class appear as undefined in the IDE.

I tried **invalidating cache** and checked **settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP Runtime** , and even **reinstalled PhpStorm**, but code that causes no warnings on my colleguaes' IDEs still flag as undefined in mine.

Comment: If you had previous version then try deleting caches manually (while IDE is closed, of course): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-54626. If nothing: check idea.log (Help | Show Log in XXX) for possible hints/provide more info. It works just fine here.

Comment: @LazyOne I didn't have a previous version, but it still worked like a charm. Thank you. Would you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some issue with PhpStorm caches on your system (quite a few people do for some reason, mainly those that had previous version) as it works just fine here.

Sadly built-in cache invalidation does not help here and you need to do this manually:

1. Close IDE.
2. Using your file manager, go to the caches folder for this IDE version and delete it. [Typical folder locations](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs):

   - Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm2020.2\caches`
   - Linux: `~/.cache/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.2/caches`
   - macOS: `~/Library/Caches/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.2/caches`

   If you have installed your IDE using Toolbox App then the folder location might be different (the exact path then can be found from `idea.log` file (`Help | Show Log in XXX`) or perhaps from Toolbox App (look for appropriate options under the "gear" icon for PhpStorm).
3. Launch IDE, open project and let it re-index the whole thing again.

---

The ticket to watch after (if you are interested): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-54626 -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.